# Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 : Foreign Key as Primary Key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, foreign-keys, primary-key

I read [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata) and some other stuff I found about it on google.

So, since Doctrine 2.1 - *if I understood right* - Doctrine can handle tables with a foreign key as primary key.

But, that doesn't work with my table !

Here is my generated Entity (with `app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src --force` ) :

```
namespace VENDOR\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ClientActivated
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client_activated")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ClientActivated
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activated", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $activated;

    /**
     * @var \VENDOR\MyBundle\Entity\Client
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VENDOR\MyBundle\Entity\Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_id_client", referencedColumnName="id_client", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $refClient;
}
```

Which says, when I `clear:cache` :

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   No identifier/primary key
>   specified for Entity "CDA\SvBundle\Entity\FidClie   ntAvantagesSv".
>   Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

I, *of course*, tried to add `@ORM\Id` on `$refClient`, remove the `JoinColumns` [...], but always the same error message when I try to clear the cache !

(And, just in case you wonder, yes I also tried to remove the `cache/*` files manually)

Comment: Because I didn't find any solution, I simply modified annotations to consider it as an normal Integer Primary Key. But it's not optimal (some methods have to be rewritten). Is it an unfixed issue ?

Comment: have you found better solution? I am having the same issue now.